# PHP shell_exec uci not working but without errors

Tags: php, exec, openwrt, luci, uhttpd

Hey all I am new at doing anything regaurding PHP Shell_exec commands.

I have some UCI code that allows me to add a rule to my fireall. This works just fine in SSH but when I try running the same thing in the PHP page it does not seem to do anything and without any error lettings me know whats going on....

My code:

```
<?php 
try {
    $cmd = "uci add firewall rule ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].name='my iphone' ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].src='lan' ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].dest='wan' ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].src_mac='XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].proto='all' ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].target='REJECT' ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].enabled='1' ".
    "commit firewall ".
    "service firewall restart ";
    
    echo 'command: ',  $cmd;

    $output = shell_exec($cmd);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

echo "<pre>output: $output</pre>";
?>
```

I've even tried adding `2>&1` at the end:

```
<?php 
try {
    $cmd = "uci add firewall rule 2>&1".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].name='my iphone' 2>&1".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].src='lan' 2>&1".
    [more code here]
```

And Ive tried using only 1 `uvi` for the whole command:

```
<?php 
try {
    $cmd = "uci add firewall rule 2>&1".
    "set firewall.@rule[-1].name='my iphone' 2>&1".
    "set firewall.@rule[-1].src='lan' 2>&1".
    [more code here]
```

And I've tried using the same as above but without the `2>&1`

```
<?php 
try {
    $cmd = "uci add firewall rule ".
    "set firewall.@rule[-1].name='my iphone' ".
    "set firewall.@rule[-1].src='lan' ".
    [more code here]
```

And lastly I've tried it with the `2>&1` just at the end of the command and with only 1 uci:

```
<?php 
try {
    $cmd = "uci add firewall rule ".
    "set firewall.@rule[-1].name='my iphone' ".
    "set firewall.@rule[-1].src='lan' ".
    [more code here]
    "service firewall restart 2>&1";
    [more code here]
```

and with each having uci:

```
<?php 
try {
    $cmd = "uci add firewall rule ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].name='my iphone' ".
    "uci set firewall.@rule[-1].src='lan' ".
    [more code here]
    "service firewall restart 2>&1";
    [more code here]
```

It first code block above outputs this on the page:
[image]

But like I said, it doesn't give any errors.

I tested a simple ls command with it and it works as expected:

[image]

So, what am I missing?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried this as requested"

```
<?php 
try {
    echo("starting..");
    shell_exec("uci add firewall rule");
    echo("1</br>");
    shell_exec("uci set firewall.@rule[-1].name='my iphone'");
    echo("2</br>");
    shell_exec("uci set firewall.@rule[-1].src='lan'");
    echo("3</br>");
    shell_exec("uci set firewall.@rule[-1].dest='wan'");
    echo("4</br>");
    shell_exec("uci set firewall.@rule[-1].src_mac='XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'");
    echo("5</br>");
    shell_exec("uci set firewall.@rule[-1].proto='all'");
    echo("6</br>");
    shell_exec("uci set firewall.@rule[-1].target='REJECT'");
    echo("7</br>");
    shell_exec("uci set firewall.@rule[-1].enabled='1'");
    echo("8</br>");
    shell_exec("commit firewall");
    echo("9</br>");
    shell_exec("service firewall restart");
    echo("10</br>");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

echo "done.";
?>
```

Which gave me this output on the page:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Comment: You probably need to put the whole command in quotes  **cmd 'command string'**

Comment: Uhm... shouldn't firewall rules be protected? Like, only root can change them? Sounds dangerous that a web script can do that...

Comment: @RohitGupta isn’t that what the “.  is doing?

Comment: @HonkderHase I’m just using this for my personal/home use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that each **uci** command is an individual line.  You can not execute multiple commands with a  **shell_exec**.

The whole command set must be one process, so separate shell_execs will just restart the process, and the previous command will be ingnored.

Create a **script** containing the commands and execute that script in **shell_exec**.

Or you can use the batch command (not tested)

```
$cmd1= "uci batch << EOI ".
       "add firewall rule ".
       "set firewall.@rule[-1].name='my iphone' ".
       "set firewall.@rule[-1].src='lan' ".
       "set firewall.@rule[-1].dest='wan' ".
       "set firewall.@rule[-1].src_mac='XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' ".
       "set firewall.@rule[-1].proto='all' ".
       "set firewall.@rule[-1].target='REJECT' ".
       "set firewall.@rule[-1].enabled='1' ".
       "commit firewall ".
       "EOI";
$cmd2= "service firewall restart ";
```

And **shell_exec** both of them.  It may require nl chars to separate the lines.

Comment: I updated my OP with your first option and again I get no errors but it's not placing that into the firewall traffic rules still.

Comment: Try using the full path to uci.

Comment: I've looked for uci in **sbin** but can not find it. Is there another path it would be in?

Comment: `/sbin/uci set firewall.@rule[-1]...` seems to not help any either.

Comment: just try one line like this `echo shell_exec ("uci xxx 2>&1");`  This should tell you if its executing uci at all.

Comment: Yes I get output when doing that. OP updated.

Comment: Use the same format and run each line with the echo and redirection.  I suspect that the error on the second line will show you that you have to put them in  a script.  Because launching shell_exec each time is a new process.

Comment: I have it working with the .sh script but I'd rather get it working just within PHP itself.

Comment: Since it has helped you. you could tick the answer